# How to remove "include-non-project items" panel from hotkey "ö" in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I started working on a program on a linux server. I am using a german keyboard. I don't know how these settings came to be but whenever I press the `ö` key, the `include-non-project items` panel pops up. I can't use the `ö` letter in my comments while programming. This is unfortunate because the program is written for a german recipient. `ä` and `ü` keys work fine, just the `ö` key seems to be put as a hotkey for the mentioned panel. There is no option in the keymap to turn it off either. On my windows machine `ö` is not bound to anything.

I am using pycharm version: `2019.2.6`

**Edit:**

I just started a new project and found this:

[image]

The `Ö` key is bound to `Search Everything`.

Comment: does the ö work correctly in other programs?

Comment: @Sadap yes, I can write text files with `ö` and it also works in the linux console

Comment: There's a "Prefer key position over key char with national layout" in Settings -> Keymap. Maybe enabling this could help? Or try uninstalling and reinstalling PyCharm if your internet connection isn't very slow